# I suggested an edit to an existing unclear question instead of asking a duplicate question, but the edit was rejected. What can I do?

Tags: discussion, questions, suggested-edits

*Background information:* Recently I encountered an issue with UITextFields freezing, and of course, the first place I came looking for an answer was Stack Overflow.

I expected to find someone's answer to the problem, but instead, there was only one (unanswered) question that was six months old at the time.  The question seemed to be about the exact same issue as the one I was having, but unfortunately, the title and the question itself weren't 100% clear and didn't have any steps to reproduce the bug.

I guessed this might have been why the question hadn't gotten any answers or even comments, so instead of posting what would have been a duplicate question, I suggested an edit to the original which clarified the title/question and added specific steps to reproduce the bug.

The edit was rejected for two different reasons.  The first was for making "drastic changes" to the original (which yes, I kind of agree with, but it was a genuine attempt at improving the question) and the second was for not being a suitable edit as it was meant to "address the author of the post".  I don't agree with this, as after six months, I assume the OP has forgotten about/abandoned the question and didn't intend the edit as a comment addressed to them anyway.  It was supposed to stand on its own as a revision.

I wasn't surprised at my suggested edit being rejected, as it *did* possibly alter the intent of the original (by providing details that may not have been valid at the time the question was originally posted).  But, since asking a new question would have been a duplicate, this leaves me unclear as to how to find an answer to the issue OP and I are both having.

**In the case that a suggested edit is considered too different from the intent of the original question, is the SO community's consensus that it should be:**

1. **asked as an entirely new question (if it isn't valid as an edit, then maybe it's not really a duplicate after all)**
2. **not asked at all (if the original didn't get answers, it might not be a good fit for the site)**
3. **posted as a comment under the original question (i.e. provide the steps to reproduce the bug, and the latest iOS versions affected, so anyone who reads the original will also have this info)**

Since this is a question about what SO 'best practice' is in general, I didn't include links to the specific question or edit review.  If you think these would improve the question though, I could add them.

*More background:*  Before posting the edit, I did also look for possible solutions or workarounds to the bug outside of Stack Overflow, but I didn't find anything definitive there either.

Comment: The edit _seems_ to maintain the original intent of the author but is still such a broad edit that by making it the author's original work is meaningless, effectively the edit would've made the question yours in practice. IMO you would've been better writing (and self-answering) your own higher quality question, and flagging the question you attempted to edit as a duplicate of your new question.

Comment: Honestly, in this specific case I wouldn't bother with editing the question. The question itself is rather bad and has no answer. Instead, ask your own question, answer it and then vote to close the other question as a dupe of your post.

Comment: @Tom OP doesn't (appear to) have an answer to the question - which is probably why they wanted to ask it.

Comment: @AdrianMole and that large answer post doesn't actually exist?

Comment: @Tom Oops - How did I completely miss that?

Comment: While we are at it: please do not add noise to posts, that's usually reason enough to get your edit rejected (specifically: "Any insights into what is causing this bug would be greatly appreciated!"). See: [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

Comment: That's great to know! The only reason I included the last part was because the original seemed to be kind of an 'open-ended' question and I was trying to keep that aspect of it. Because of how long the text field issue seems to have persisted, I doubt that there is an official 'answer', but was hoping for either a better workaround than my own solution, or, preferably, an explanation for the cause of the bug (mine is only a guess).  I also didn't know you could post a new question and flag an older one for deletion.

Comment: If a question is unanswered then it cannot be a duplicate candidate for another question. Sounds like you should have just asked your own clear detailed question

Comment: Update:  while typing a title for my new question this came up in the similar questions results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186118/uitextfield-causing-app-to-freeze-on-ios-8 and this seems very likely to be the issue

Comment: The iOS version is different, and for them the issue appears to happen when the UITextField is _selected_ without regards to # of characters typed, **but** the key point is that the text field element contains (an implicit?) call to viewWillLayoutSubviews.  This method is where I did all the custom formatting in my program, so it appears that setting the field width and font size in here does in fact cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case, it appears that creating a duplicate question would have been the way to go.  You could then provide the details relevant to your use case and your reproduction details without guessing at the intent of the original asker.

This could have been followed up by marking the original as a duplicate of yours, as it has no preexisting answers and no details reproduction steps.

If the existing question had just been poorly written, but had a high quality answer that directly solved your need, creating the duplicate would not have been appropriate.  If that were the case, it might have made sense to make some minimal efforts to clarify the question, while being careful not to overstep.

Comment: "This could have been followed up by marking the original as a duplicate of yours" why should we do that? There's no meaningful information in the close question to produce an answer, so it may as well just be deleted.

Comment: @Braiam Because a question generally needs to be closed before it can be deleted, and a proper reason for closure in this case is that it's a duplicate.

Comment: No, the proper reason is unclear. Duplicate questions are answerable questions that have been asked before. This question is not answerable due lack of information.